# I Need Improve My Code Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I Need Improve My Code Jquery , the page sometimes crash the browser i dont know why and load slowly

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
                                   anim();
                        });

                        function anim() {
                                  $("#BS1").fadeOut("slow").delay(290).fadeIn("slow");
                                  $("#BS2").fadeIn("slow").delay(320).fadeOut("slow");
                                  $("#BS3").fadeOut("slow").delay(180).fadeIn("slow");
                                  $("#BS4").fadeIn("slow").delay(380).fadeOut("slow");
                                  $("#BS5").fadeIn("slow").delay(200).fadeOut("slow");
                                  $("#BS6").fadeIn("slow").delay(600).fadeOut("slow");
                                  $("#BS7").fadeOut("slow").delay(320).fadeIn("slow");
                                  $("#BS8").fadeIn("slow").delay(150).fadeOut("slow");
                                  $("#BS9").fadeOut("slow").delay(360).fadeIn("slow");
                                  $("#BS10").fadeIn("slow").delay(185).fadeOut("slow");
                                  $("#BS11").fadeIn("slow").delay(150).fadeOut("slow");
                                  $("#BS12").fadeOut("slow").delay(360).fadeIn("slow");
                                  $("#BS13").fadeIn("slow").delay(175).fadeOut("slow");
                                  $("#BS14").fadeOut("slow").delay(250).fadeIn("slow");
                                  anim();
                        }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [codereview.se]

Comment: you are creating continues animations and the call will cause stack overflow also

Comment: Sorry Guys About That

Comment: I Suggest u to use MooTools "Chaining" feature [Link](http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Chaining)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `anim()` within `anim()`.

Remove the `anim()` from the bottom of your function.

```
function anim() {
   $("#BS1").fadeOut("slow").delay(290).fadeIn("slow");
   $("#BS2").fadeIn("slow").delay(320).fadeOut("slow");
   $("#BS3").fadeOut("slow").delay(180).fadeIn("slow");
   $("#BS4").fadeIn("slow").delay(380).fadeOut("slow");
   $("#BS5").fadeIn("slow").delay(200).fadeOut("slow");
   $("#BS6").fadeIn("slow").delay(600).fadeOut("slow");
   $("#BS7").fadeOut("slow").delay(320).fadeIn("slow");
   $("#BS8").fadeIn("slow").delay(150).fadeOut("slow");
   $("#BS9").fadeOut("slow").delay(360).fadeIn("slow");
   $("#BS10").fadeIn("slow").delay(185).fadeOut("slow");
   $("#BS11").fadeIn("slow").delay(150).fadeOut("slow");
   $("#BS12").fadeOut("slow").delay(360).fadeIn("slow");
   $("#BS13").fadeIn("slow").delay(175).fadeOut("slow");
   $("#BS14").fadeOut("slow").delay(250).fadeIn("slow");
}
```

If you want it to repeat then try putting it in the callback as suggested. It would look like this.

`$("#BS6").fadeIn("slow").delay(600).fadeOut("slow", anim)`

Comment: He may want it to repeat, so I'd suggest putting it in the callback for the `#BS6` `.fadeOut()` as that'll be the last one to finish.